# SQL - find and replace within one column based on query on another

Tags: sql, wordpress, phpmyadmin, sql-update

I don't do too much SQL so need help with something simple.

I have the following `Table`:

```
ID term value
--------------
1 term1 slug/
2 term1 slug/
3 term2 something/something
4 term2 slug/
5 term3 slash-/-something
```

What I want to do is to FIND `/` in column `value`and REPLACE with an empty string BUT only where `term` is equal to `term1`

The result would be:

```
ID term value
--------------
1 term1 slug
2 term1 slug
3 term2 something/something
4 term2 slug/
5 term3 slash-/-something
```

I can SELECT everything in `term` that is equal to `term1`, and I can FIND AND REPLACE everything in `value` with a `/`, but I can't seem to figure out how to combine the two operations together.

*Note: I recognize there's no FIND AND REPLACE operation.*

Comment: What are you talking about? `I recognize there's no FIND AND REPLACE operation`??? Wordpress usually uses MySql, you just need an update on this table `update value = replace(value, '/','') where term = 'term1'`

Comment: I meant specifically that I'm aware it's not called FIND AND REPLACE. And, unfortunately what you provided doesn't work

Comment: How did you run it and what was the error message?

Comment: Oooh I see the error, I did not put the table name on the update command: `update yourTableNameHere set value = replace(value, '/','') where term = 'term1'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to execute an `Update` command in the database:

```
update yourTableNameHere 
   set value = replace(value, '/','') 
 where term = 'term1'
```

Comment: Thanks. this makes sense now that I see It together.

Comment: Glad that I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
SELECT ID, term, CASE  WHEN term = 'term1' THEN REPLACE(value, '/','')
        ELSE value
    END AS value
FROM tablename
```